# QGIS Atlas pages with different raster base layers?

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to enable raster layers only for specific Atlas pages, without using multiple map Windows?

Unfortunately, there is no way to set transparency of raster layers by an expression function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer by myself.

It is possible by using python expression functions inside a composer label.
All we have to do is: enable/disable the raster layer one page before it should be visible/hidden.

Here are the expression functions:

```
@qgsfunction(1, 'Atlas')
def EnableRasterLayer(values,feature,parent):
    rasterLayer = values[0]
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(rasterLayer)[0]
    legend = iface.legendInterface()
    legend.setLayerVisible(layer, True)
    return ""

@qgsfunction(1, 'Atlas')
def DisableRasterLayer(values,feature,parent):
    rasterLayer = values[0]
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(rasterLayer)[0]
    legend = iface.legendInterface()
    legend.setLayerVisible(layer, False)
    return ""
```

And here is the label text to enable 'mybasemap' for atlas page 'Page 3/5':

```
[%CASE 
    WHEN @atlas_pagename = 'Page 2/5' THEN EnableRasterLayer( 'mybasemap')
    WHEN @atlas_pagename = 'Page 3/5' THEN DisableRasterLayer( 'mybasemap')
END%]
```